# Routing Issue Prevents Display of Image from Database

Tags: image, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an MVC C# .net Core application. Code is still a work in progress. I'm trying to display an image stored from TinyMce in a SqlServer Database and one of my routes seems to add an extra directory address in the url. So, I figure this is a routing issue, but I'm open to other ideas.

I've searched the web and read microsoft docs, but can't seem to figure out the correct route.

This action method works correctly. Notice there is no {id} parameter.
Displays image correctly in the list.
When View Image is clicked in browser produces the following route...
localhost:44353/images/users/MyImage.jpg

```
    [Route("/[controller]/PostList")]
    public IActionResult PostList(Guid tagId, Guid authorId, int numPerPage = 10)
    {
        ICollection<Post> posts;
        string currentTag = string.Empty;
        string currentAuthor = string.Empty;

        if (tagId == Guid.Empty && authorId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            posts = _blogRepository.GetRecentPosts(numPerPage).ToList();
            currentTag = "All posts";
            currentAuthor = "All authors";
        }
        else if (!(tagId == Guid.Empty) && authorId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            Tag tag = _tagRepository.GetAllTags().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == tagId);
            posts = _blogRepository.GetPostsByTag(tag).OrderBy(p => p.ModifiedDate).ToList();
            currentTag = tag.Content;
            currentAuthor = "All authors";
        }
        else if (!(authorId == Guid.Empty) && tagId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            Author author = _authorRepository.Authors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == authorId);
            posts = _blogRepository.GetPostsByAuthor(author).OrderBy(p => p.ModifiedDate).ToList();
            currentTag = "All posts";
            currentAuthor = author.AuthorName;
        }
        else
            posts = _blogRepository.GetRecentPosts(numPerPage).ToList();

        return View(new PostListViewModel
        {
            CurrentTag = currentTag,
            CurrentAuthor = currentAuthor,
            Posts = posts,
            AllTags = _tagRepository.GetAllTags().ToList(),
            AllAuthors = _authorRepository.Authors.ToList()
        });
    }
```

This Action method does not display the image
When View Image is clicked in browser produces the following route...
localhost:44353/Blog/images/users/MyImage.jpg
Adding {id} apparently changes the route...
I tried several different routes to no avail...

```
    [Route("/[controller]/PostDetail/{id}")]
    public IActionResult PostDetail(Guid id)
    {
        var post = _blogRepository.FindCurrentPost(id);
        if (post == null)
            return NotFound();

        return View(new PostDetailViewModel() {
            Post = post,
            AllAuthors = _authorRepository.Authors.ToList(),
            AllTags = _tagRepository.GetAllTags().ToList()
        });
    }
```

Would like to be able to display the image and have the correct route.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!

I removed all the routes that were stomping the PostDetail Route and added a very simple route to remove "Blog" from the url. I don't know why I had to remove it for the detail but could leave it in the list (I suspect a bug in the version of .net core I'm using which is 2.0.9., but I really don't know.

This is the route to remove the controller from the URL (note: worked only after remove most other routes I defined for the controller first...) Now the image will show up.

```
    [Route("PostDetail/{id}")]
    public IActionResult PostDetail(Guid id)
    {
        var post = _blogRepository.FindCurrentPost(id);
        if (post == null)
            return NotFound();

        return View(new PostDetailViewModel() {
            Post = post,
            AllAuthors = _authorRepository.Authors.ToList(),
            AllTags = _tagRepository.GetAllTags().ToList()
        });
    }
```